# C++ : Implicit type conversion

Tags: c++

I am bit confused about implicit type conversion. Given the following program

```
   float x = 4.23423451;
   double y = 4.23423451;

   float z = 101.9876;

   float res1 = x * z;
   float res2 = y * z;

   std::cout << "res1 & res2 " << res1 << "  & " << res2 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "equality " << (res1 == res2) << std::endl;
```

The output was

```
   res1 & res2 431.839  & 431.839
   equality 1
```

My question is "Will the equality be always true for any value of x, y & z (x = y) and also for any compiler?"

In

> res2 = y * z;

Will the variable "y" be type-casted to float or variable "z" be type-casted to double?

Comment: This is well-defined. The intermediate expression for `z` will undergo widening into `double`, so `y * z` will be a `double` expression. An implicit narrowing conversion will then convert it to `float` for storing in `res2`. Same applies to `res1`.

Comment: That being said, `res1` need not necessarily be equivalent to `res2` -- it is highly dependent on the precision of `float` and `double` in the environment. The two literals could potentially not even be equal -- `4.23423451f` not need be equivalent to `4.23423451`.

Comment: if you are using visual studio: goto project properties -> C/C++ -> general -> warning level. set it to level 3. in the warnings section of the error window it will show casts that are not cast by you manually. im sure another IDE will have something similar. hope it helps

Comment: @QuantumKarl - a point about terminology: a **cast** is something you write in your source code. It tells the compiler to do a **conversion**. There are also situations where the compiler will do a **conversion** without a **cast**. These are called **implicit conversions**.

Comment: @Pete - thanks noted, its still being converted either way. with the warning setting increased the compiler will warn you about any conversion you don't manually tell the compiler to do with a cast. the code above generates this "warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data" on res2 = y * z; telling you that y is being converted to a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396132/c-implicit-type-conversion#comment16656609_12396132).

> This is well-defined. The intermediate expression for `z` will undergo widening into `double`, so `y * z` will be a `double` expression. An implicit narrowing conversion will then convert it to `float` for storing in `res2`. This same narrowing applies to `res1`.

This is reflected by **§5¶9 Expressions [expr]** of the C++11 standard.

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.
>
> ...

This, however, does not sure that the equality will hold.

> That being said, `res1` need not necessarily be equivalent to `res2` -- it is highly dependent on the precision of `float` and `double` in the environment. The two literals could potentially not even be equal -- `4.23423451f` not need even be equivalent to `4.23423451`. You can not be sure that `static_cast<double>(static_cast<float>(4.23423451))` will be equal to `4.23423451`.

See **§5.17¶3 Assignment and compound assignment operators [expr.ass]**.

> If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand.

**§4 Standard conversions [conv]** states as follows:

> Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A *standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>
> ...
>
> - Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, and boolean conversions.

As elaborated in **§4.6 Floating point promotion [conv.fpprom]**,

> 1. A prvalue of type `float` can be converted to a prvalue of type `double`. The value is unchanged.
> 2. This conversion is called *floating point promotion*.

... and **§4.8 Floating point conversions [conv.double]**,

> 1. A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> 2. The conversions allowed as floating point promotions are excluded from the set of floating point conversions.

The problem here is that we have multiple cases where our conversion is not *promotion*, but rather narrowing to a potentially lower-precision type (`double` to `float`).

Essentially, any time you convert `double` to `float`, you may potentially lose precision.

Answer (score 3):

You should **never** compare floating point values for equality.

Comment: Except when you should, as, for example, in the question at hand. `<g>`

Comment: @PeteBecker: Can you explain why you should compare for equality in the code above? There are many things that can make the result *slightly* different and the equality test fail even if the values **are** the same. For example, some architectures have larger floating point registers than `double` (80 vs. 64) if you calculate an operation and the value is written to memory, you perform the same calculation an then compare the value in the result register with the value read from memory they can differ.

Comment: Floating point variables are perfectly fine citizens. If you say `float x = 1.1; float y = x;` then it is definitely guaranteed that `x == y` is true. What you should do is make assumptions about *computations* involving them.

Comment: Because the question was whether the two values will always be equal. It's about the effects of floating-point conversions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The problem is that the equality is a bitwise equality, not a semantic equality, and that will fail in cases where the values are the same. Read the previous comment. Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @PeteBecker: *My question is "Will the equality be always true for any value of x, y & z (x = y) and also for any compiler?"* --> NO, not even all of the values are `double` that equality is guaranteed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm pretty sure that the equality operator also semantic. We're not writing `memcmp` code here! The point is that floating point types aren't inherently "wobbly" or "fuzzy" or "broken". It's really all just about *computations*. `0.1` is always `0.1` (as a typed value), but it is *not* true that `2 * 0.1` is the same as `0.2`...

Comment: On the contrary: if all the values are double, C and C++ require the same result. The results can differ if they are compared directly and not stored into a variable of the appropriate type, precisely to allow the stuff like Intel does with 80-bit math.

Comment: @KerrekSB - yes, == is semantic. For example, -0 and 0 compare equal. But that's the only case (with IEEE math) where two different bit patterns represent the same value. And once you throw NaNs into the mix, it's definitely not bit-equivalence, since `a==a` is false when `a` is a NaN.

Comment: @KerrekSB - David is looking at the tricks that are allowed, such as performing math at higher precision then converting back to the required type. You can get weird-looking results, like in `double a = b * c; assert(a == b * c);` and the `assert` triggers, because the compiler computed `b * c` as an 80-bit value, which got rounded when it was stored into `a`, but didn't get rounded for the comparison. That's nasty, but avoidable: just store the second result into a variable of the same type (and maybe set a compiler flag to tell it that it should handle floating-point math by the rules).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not guaranteed. `x` and `y` do not necessarily have the same value. <s>It is true that both are promoted to `double` in the expressions `x * z` and `y * z`, but the result of promoting `x` to a double need not equal the value of `y`.</s> Whereas `x * z` is evaluated as a `float`, the expression `y * z` promotes `z` to double, and the results of the multiplications needn't be equal, so that the conversion back to the narrower type may result in different values.

Comment: In the question `x` and `z` are both of type `float`.

Comment: @JesseGood - I think the point was that `x` and `y` have different values when `x` is promoted to double.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Why is `x` promoted to double? It is only used in the expression `float res1 = x * z;` in which all values are `float`s.

Comment: @JesseGood - `x` is not promoted to double.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Um, your comment says `when x is promoted to double`. I was pointing out that the answer says `promoted to double in the expressions x * z`, which is not true because `x` and `z` are `float`s.

Comment: @JesseGood: You're right, there's no promotion in `x * z`. I changed the answer. `y * z` may still have a different value from `x * z` after being narrowed back to float. `y` and `z` may have different values (as doubles) than `x` and `z` have (as floats).

Comment: @JesseGood - don't know what I was thinking with "when `x` is promoted to double. I think it was a leftover from a previous draft.

Answer (score 0):

The casting should remain the same; however, I have seen processor and os impact the actual mathematics at high precision.

But, all that aside, use [static_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) to be explicit:

```
float res2 = static_cast<float>(y * static_cast<double>(z));
```

This way everyone knows what you mean and that you mean to be casting things about.

Comment: There are no **casts** in the original code. The question is about **implicit conversions**, and making them explicit with a cast doesn't affect what they do. Of course, casting to the wrong type will mess up the results...

Comment: @PB I'm not sure why, but the web page ate the angle brackets even though the preview showed them.  And I used them to show the alternative of being explicit for the sake of being explicit as listed in the post.  And despite the "everyone should know everything" theory, I frequently find that people don't know certain things when they are skimming through, so at times like this, I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: Yup, the forum software can be deceiving. They're there now. Still, I wouldn't use a cast for an implicit conversion, both because I might get it wrong, and because in future maintenance the types might change and the cast would be wrong.

Comment: That's an interesting debate; however, static_cast was created to be _obvious_ to both reader and text scanner.  One thing you might check when changing such as to C++11 is whether such rules changed.  If they did, grep for static casts.

Comment: The rules for floating-point math did not change with C++11, nor did the rules for static_cast. But casts are for telling the compiler what to do when it can't or won't do what you want. If you want documentation, write comments, not casts.

Comment: I know they didn't and likely won't.  But when you're doing something you are worried about a junior programmer coming along and mis-understanding -- or worse yet, taking over to a different processor architecture where the _sizes_ of datatypes might change -- you can tell the programmer and the compiler what you want.  However, the point is lost for the arguing.