# Qt - Converting float to QString

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion

This seems like it should be very simple, but I'm going through the docs and not seeing anything. I just need to convert a number that is represented as a `float` object into a `QString` object. I know there is the function `QString::number()` that can be used for other types like `int` and `double`, like so:
`int a = 1;
 QString b = QString::number(a);`

...however this doesn't seem to work for `float`. Perhaps there is some way where it is converted first from `float` to another type, and then from that type to `QString`? If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: *...however this doesn't seem to work for float* You mean you tried it and something went wrong, or just that it's not documented as existing for float? (If the former, elaborate on what "didn't work".)

Comment: Sometimes you just have to try it out. It so happens that [it just works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), and it has nothing to do with Qt at all, but everything to do with C++ :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ : Implicit type conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396132/c-implicit-type-conversion)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`float` will auto-promote to `double` when needed

```
float pi = 3.14; 
QString b = QString::number(pi);
```

should work

otherwise you can use setNum:

```
float pi = 3.14; 
QString b;
b.setNum(pi);
```

Comment: just to clarify, in the answer does a = pi?

Comment: no worries, that worked btw, I saw in the docs it could use double, but didn't realize it would automatically make that change for float. Thanks! :)

Comment: For completeness, `QString::arg` is a third way to do this.